# Can you declare a fixed-length array in a function declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, allocation

I'm reading some C++ code (SGP4, a satellite propagation code) and I found the following function declaration:

```
void twoline2rv(char longstr1[130], char longstr2[130], char typerun,
            char typeinput, char opsmode, gravconsttype whichconst,
            double &startmfe, double &stopmfe, double &deltamin,
            elsetrec &satrec);
```

I'm wondering what it means to say `char longstr1[130]` in a function argument.  Why does the compiler need to know that the array is 130 bytes long?  And why not say `char *longstr1`?

Comment: I'd recommend to use `std::array` instead.

Comment: It's not my code.

Comment: I've reopened the Q as it appears the OP knows about array decaying.  They are wondering why the Author did not use it.

Comment: This is one of those sneaky c++ gotchas. In every other case `char longstr1[130]` would mean an array of 130 `char`s. But in function parameters it's actually a `char*` and the size is never enforced or checked. At best, it's an indication of the *expected* array size for others who would use the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver On rereading I'm not sure about that. They do suggest `char*` as an alternative, but given that they're asking what `char[130]` here _does_ (and that they ask in the title whether the obvious interpretation is possible) I think a broad answer is called for. Dupe probably not directly useful, agreed.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of misleading code. Those parameters *literally* do mean `char *longstr1` (ugh). There is no bounds checking, nothing. You can pass a pointer to an array of any length. Seems you know this already.

Now, one might argue that this approach is self-documenting, but I'd say it's documenting a lie. If the pointer "should" have a specific bound then this ought to be documented with comments above the function's declaration, rather than suggesting to readers that it'll be enforced by type. It's possible that the *author* thought that!

Ultimately, to really find out why it's been written that way, you should track down the author and ask them. Anything else is guesswork.

Comment: Or one could pass by reference which would force passing an array of the stated size.

Comment: Thanks.  This makes sense.  The author isn't a software engineer at all.  I know why the string length should be 130 characters: the input string is always 130 characters because of the two line element format (see celestrak.com if you want to know more).

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing; the declaration decays to `char *longstr1`, but it's more informative to someone reading the API that it expects a buffer of exactly 130 characters.